# How to insert bulk csv file into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, insert

I have a csv file that have columns like this

```
"Hold","EmpID","Source","Shard-Exists","Type"
```

but my DB table look like this

```
//Note: My Id is auto increment
"Id","Hold","EmpID","Source","Type","CurrentDate"
```

I'm just wondering how can bulk insert my csv file into the database table without the shard-Exist column and also passing the Current Date automatically.

Any help or suggestion will be really appreciated

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Actors;
GO
 
-- import the file
BULK INSERT dbo.Actors
FROM 'C:\Documents\Skyvia\csv-to-mssql\actor.csv'
WITH
(
        FORMAT='CSV',
        FIRSTROW=2
)
GO
```

Comment: You've tagged *MySql* but state SQL Server...?

Comment: And I see this asked at least once a day ..

Comment: @CaiusJard - if that's the case, you have a high enough reputation to vote to close the question as a duplicate. That would be helpful to the OP as presumably the duplicate would solve their technical problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a format file to accomplish the 'skip columns in table' task. I'll modify the example from [the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-skip-a-table-column-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="https://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="7"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="25" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="25" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="25" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="25" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="30" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Hold" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="EmpID" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Source" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="Type" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Note, in the `<ROW>` portion that I'm not specifying anything for the ID or CurrentDate columns. It's also noteworthy that there's no `SOURCE="5"`; that's how the `Shard-Exists` field in the source data is being skipped.

As to auto-generating a value for `CurrentDate`, my recommendation would be to add a default constraint to your table. that can be done like so:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Actors
   ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Actors__CurrentDate
   DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR CurrentDate;
```